# Apply left_join for specific rows

Tags: r

Suppose I have 2 *data.frames* that I want to merge. Data as follows:

```
options(scipen = 999)

LHS <- structure(
   
   list(
      v1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
      v2 = c("one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one"),
      v3 = c("two", "two", "two", "two", "two", "two"),
      v4 = c("xx", "zz", NA_character_, "yy", NA_character_, NA_character_),
      v5 = c("xx", "zz", NA_character_, "yy", NA_character_, NA_character_)),
   
   .Names = c("id", "first var","second var", "var of interest 1", "var of interest 2"),
   .typeOf = c("numeric", "character", "character","character","character"),
   row.names = c(NA, -6L),
   class = "data.frame"
   
   ) # end of LHS `structure`
   
   
RHS <- structure(
   
   list(
      v1 = c(3, 5, 6, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000),
      v2 = c("QWERTY", "QWERTY", "QWERTY", "QWERTY", "QWERTY", "QWERTY", "QWERTY", "QWERTY"),
      v3 = c("QWERTY", "QWERTY", "QWERTY", "QWERTY", "QWERTY", "QWERTY", "QWERTY", "QWERTY")),
   
   .Names = c("id", "var of interest 1", "var of interest 2"),
   .typeOf = c("numeric", "character","character"),
   row.names = c(NA, -8L),
   class = "data.frame"
   
) # end of RHS `structure`
```

In LHS *data.frame* some rows with id 3, 5 and 6 have missing values. So I want to use `left_join` to combine my LHS and RHS, however, I am interested only in rows with missing values in variables of interest. In other words, I want to implement `left_join` to rows with missing values in particular columns (e.g. var of interest 1 and var of interest 2). Note, that RHS *data.frames* (I would have more than 1) do not contain data for rows (id) that already present in LHS *data.frame*.

The only one solution I figured out was to use `lapply` over all rows and implement `left_join` for those which contain missing values in particular columns (id 3, 5 and 6). `lapply` could be upgraded to `mclapply` to speed up execution time, however, for long *data.frames* such operation could be pricy.

Another one possible solution is to divide data.frames into two: with and without missing values, perform left_join and combine them together.

I am looking for more gentle solution. Any ides?

**UPDATED** desired output:

```
structure(

   list(
      v1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
      v2 = c("one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one"),
      v3 = c("two", "two", "two", "two", "two", "two"),
      v4 = c("xx", "zz", "QWERTY", "yy", "QWERTY", "QWERTY"),
      v5 = c("xx", "zz", "QWERTY", "yy", "QWERTY", "QWERTY")),

   .Names = c("id", "first var","second var", "var of interest 1", "var of interest 2"),
   .typeOf = c("numeric", "character", "character","character","character"),
   row.names = c(NA, -6L),
   class = "data.frame"

   )
```

Comment: What is the desired output from your shared sample data?

Comment: I've added an output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following `tidyverse` way may also help in doing as expected for any number of `vars of interest`

```
LHS %>% left_join(RHS, by = 'id') %>%
  mutate(across(ends_with('.x'), ~coalesce(., get(str_replace(cur_column(), '.x', '.y'))))) %>%
  select(!(ends_with('.y')))

  id first var second var var of interest 1.x var of interest 2.x
1  1       one        two                  xx                  xx
2  2       one        two                  zz                  zz
3  3       one        two              QWERTY              QWERTY
4  4       one        two                  yy                  yy
5  5       one        two              QWERTY              QWERTY
6  6       one        two              QWERTY              QWERTY
```

If you want to rename back your cols, do this

```
LHS %>% left_join(RHS, by = 'id') %>%
  mutate(across(ends_with('.x'), ~coalesce(., get(str_replace(cur_column(), '.x', '.y'))))) %>%
  select(!(ends_with('.y'))) %>%
  rename_with(~str_remove(., '.x'), ends_with('.x'))

  id first var second var var of interest 1 var of interest 2
1  1       one        two                xx                xx
2  2       one        two                zz                zz
3  3       one        two            QWERTY            QWERTY
4  4       one        two                yy                yy
5  5       one        two            QWERTY            QWERTY
6  6       one        two            QWERTY            QWERTY
```

Answer (score 4):

`data.table` update join would be helpful here.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(LHS)
setDT(RHS)

cols <- c("var of interest 1", "var of interest 2")
LHS[RHS, on = .(id), (cols) := mget(paste0('i.', cols))]
LHS

#   id first var second var var of interest 1 var of interest 2
#1:  1       one        two                xx                xx
#2:  2       one        two                zz                zz
#3:  3       one        two            QWERTY            QWERTY
#4:  4       one        two                yy                yy
#5:  5       one        two            QWERTY            QWERTY
#6:  6       one        two            QWERTY            QWERTY
```

Comment: Interesting!  Can you please translate it to `dplyr` so that I may improve for future?

Comment: I don't think `dplyr` has update join functionality so if you want to do this in `dplyr` what you have done should be the way. Join and then check for corresponding columns in parallel and update.